# Can't host my own hidden service

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing, website

I use lighttpd, i can access localhost with Firefox, use port 9000,
I modified my `torrc` with this port;

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Reload, restart..but can't connect to my .onion in tor.  I get this error:

```
Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.

We can’t connect to the server at xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.onion.

If that address is correct, here are three other things you can try:

    Try again later.
    Check your network connection.
    If you are connected but behind a firewall, check that Tor Browser has permission to access the Web.
```

I test the same config on ubuntu & debian.

---

Update:

my .onion is an v3 56caracters then i added this line to my torrc:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service
HiddenServiceVersion 3
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Right look like:

```
root@debian:/var/lib/tor# ls -l
total 5572
drwx--S--- 3 119 avahi    4096 Nov  5 08:33 hidden_service



root@debian:/var/lib/tor/hidden_service# ls -l
total 16
drwx--S--- 2 119 avahi 4096 Nov  2 07:42 authorized_clients
-rwx------ 1 119 avahi   63 Nov  2 16:40 hostname
-rwx------ 1 119 avahi   64 Nov  2 07:42 hs_ed25519_public_key
-rwx------ 1 119 avahi   96 Nov  2 07:42 hs_ed25519_secret_key
```

Btw i cant access with localhost:9000 on Firefox. But with localhost:80 & localhost it work. (i put port 9000 on config)
I followed this guide for install my server: https://www.osradar.com/how-to-install-lighttpd-web-server-on-ubuntu-18-04/

I only test with Ubuntu & Debian, never in Windows.

Comment: What do the logs for the onion service tor server say?

Comment: This folder is empty /var/log/tor

Comment: @hiddentor You can edit your question and add new information if you want. I updated your question with the information from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem...my server is savant, do know much on this, but i suspect is something with the v3 onions, it generated a 52string.onion wich display the same log.
I saw that:
"How to setup your own prop224 service

It's easy! Just use your ​regular onion service torrc and add HiddenServiceVersion 3 in your onion service torrc block. ` Here is an example torrc designed for testing:

SocksPort auto

HiddenServiceDir /home/user/tmp/hsv3
HiddenServiceVersion 3
HiddenServicePort 6667 127.0.0.1:6667

Then your onion address is in /home/user/tmp/hsv3/hostname. To host both a v2 and a v3 service using two onion service torrc blocks:

HiddenServiceDir /home/user/tmp/hsv2
HiddenServicePort 6667 127.0.0.1:6667

HiddenServiceDir /home/user/tmp/hsv3
HiddenServiceVersion 3
HiddenServicePort 6668 127.0.0.1:6667

Please note that tor is strict about directory permissions and does not like to share its files. Make sure to restrict read and write access to the onion services directory before restarting tor. For most linux based systems

chmod 700 -R /var/lib/tor

should be intended.

To restart tor it's safer to not use SIGHUP directly (see bug #21818), but to check the validity of the config first. On Debian based systems the services management tool does this for you:

```
service tor restart"
```

I do not understand this much and is just for Linux, is´n it?
 I would appreciate any in formation on this , thank ypu very much.
M. Almeida

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the.onion through the 9000 port You need to add
'HiddenServicePort 9000'
If you want to access the. Onion through port 80 you need to have lighttpd listen on port 9000